"Similar is the case with visits to galleries." — Is "similar" an adjective here or a fused modifier-head noun phrase?
Could you help me please to parse the word "similar" when it stands at the beginning of sentences and has no head-noun after itself?

google.com/search:

... in the theatre audience one does not normally find farmers (94.5 % of the group), workers (81.6 % of the group) and small business owners (79.4 % of the group). Similar is the case with visits to galleries/museums.

first example:
(1) Similar is the case with visits to galleries.

google.com/search:

A series of these monuments are to be seen in the Temple Church in London. The earliest, perhaps, is the tomb of Geoffrey de Magnavilla, Count of Essex. He is depicted with hard features, and in an advancing attitude, which is rendered still more apparent from the inflated drapery. His right hand is lying on his breast; his left holds the shield. Similar is the figure of Lord de Ros, only somewhat more soft in treatment: the right hand is again resting on the breast, and the left hand holds the sword.

second example:
(2) Similar is the figure of Lord de Ros.

I'm interested to parse the word "similar" in (1) and (2).
It seems to me "similar" is parsed the same way in both (1) and (2).
Is "similar" an adjective here or a fused modifier-head noun phrase (i.e. "similar" means "similar case" and "similar figure") ?
Is there a copular inversion here where "similar" functions as a subject complement?

As far as I understood from various internet examples, whether to use "is" or "are" doesn't depend on "similar":
"Similar is the case ..." and "Similar are the cases ..." are correct.
"Similar are the case ..." and "Similar is the cases ..." are not correct.
Does this prove that with this word order, "similar" can be only a subject complement, but not a subject?

'Blue is the colour of my true love's eyes' = 'The colour of my true love's eyes is blue.' Simple Comp - Vₗᵢₙₖ - S inversion for style. Admittedly, 'similar' is a rather more complex adjective than 'blue' which simply describes an inherent attribute of the subject's referent.

This question is similar to: Is it correct to place the adjective before is/was in a sentence and  Is it possible to start a sentence with "worse than"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I think your cited text is a somewhat imperfect translation (or at least, author Predrag Cvetičanin isn't a native Anglophone). He uses that slightly peculiar inversion Similar is the case with X (as opposed to the standard English sequence The case with X is similar) more than once in the cited publication. Checking written C21 instances of Similar is the case with... in Google Books, I have the impression most of them are probably from non-native Anglophone writers (most of the authors' names look "foreign" to me).

@FF Fluent writers could well use such inversions as style choices.

@EdwinAshworth "Similar" can't be a noun. "Blue" can. "Blue" is an uncountable noun in "Her favorite color is blue", an example from britannica.com. So "similar" in the original post is not analogous to "blue".

@EdwinAshworth: I don't deny it. But mostly they wouldn't, and I think there's an unquestionable preponderance of foreign-looking names in the results from my C21 Google Books search. And although I can't repeat the confirmation, I saw at least one other instance of a sentence starting with Similar is in the cited publication (I'm fairly certain it was at least two others, possibly more). So I suspect that specific type of "fronted" inversion is more common in at least Serbian than it is in English. Whatever - one doesn't normally use a "slightly marked" form multiple times

@FumbleFingers If you searched "similar are/is" in the CGEL, you would find several results with "similar is" (though no one with the noun "case") and two with "similar are" (one of them is "Quite similar are cases like ...").

@Lovii 'Weak is the effort of my heart / And cold my warmest thought ...' [John Newton] are uncontestably  Compₐₔⱼ - Vₗᵢₙₖ - S inversions (the second with gapping). // I'd say 'Their condition is poor' displays an adjective usage, not a noun one, for 'poor'.  Perhaps one can posit 'the status we call' as a deletion. Similarly with 'The colour of my true love's eyes is [the colour identified as] blue.'


Does this prove that with this word order, "similar" can be only a subject complement, but not a subject?

No. [Similar can be a substantive noun phrase. "The vase is not unique. Similar were found in Egypt." As it happens, this is not the case in your example. Your example is chiefly literary/poetic style.]
The construction "Adverb/Adjective + verb + subject is linked to Old English where the verb in the sentence was the second element.
The verb agrees with the subject, and thus "Similar is/was/has, etc" and similar are/were/have, etc. are possible and correct.
This inversion is found in Modern English (mainly locative) where an adverb or an adjective (or prepositional phrase) fronts a sentence:
"Here (= at this place) are your keys and there (at that place) is your hat."
"In the garden stands a statue" -> In the garden stand statues
and in literary style (now mainly archaic):
"Deep was my love for her, but long was the journey to her heart."

If you searched "similar are/is" in the CGEL, you would find several results with "similar is" ("Similar is its use with the meaning “experience”: ...", "Somewhat similar is "change", which ..."; "Similar is "move", as in ..."; "Similar is "deepfreeze", but ...") and two results with "similar are" ("Similar are examples like ..."; "Quite similar are cases like ..."). Does this mean "similar" can also be used in modern English in a non-poetic and non-literary style? Thanks.

I'm not sure what point you are making but I have amended my answer for clarity. Similar in some of your examples seems to be = Similar ones", i.e. a substantive, and this can be a subject or object. However, in other examples, it seems to be an adjective and as such cannot be the subject or object.

I meant CGEL is a textbook published in 2002, i.e. the language used there is not old. CGEL has the sentences beginning with "Similar is" and "Similar are" which I cited in the first comment. But you said "Similar is" and "Similar are" are now used only in literary style. Then why does CGEL use them? It's a scientific book, not literary one. That is, it doesn't use a literary style, it's written in scientific manner. Hence "Similar is" and "Similar are" can now be used not only in literary style, as you said. Is it so? Thanks.

"Uneasy lies the head that wears a crown." Sounds Shakespearean, so I'd use this construction for an artful effect only. Similar adjective use of uneasy and similar.

It was unclear whether your example was the use of "similar" as an adjective or a substantive - you gave no context. Similar, as a substantive (=A similar one, or similar ones) is a noun that requires a referent and its number depends on the number of its referent. You gave no context/referent and I and others assumed you were using it as an adjective.
